# Why “can” not “could” in “She was one of those people who can. . . .”?

Tags: past-tense, modal-verbs, backshifting, subordinate-clauses, sequence-of-tenses

The following sentence is from [George Orwell’s *Nineteen Eighty-Four*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteen_Eighty-Four), occurring in chapter 5 of part 2:

> She was one of those people who can go to sleep at any hour and in any position.

Why is *who can* grammatically correct when used with *was*? Shouldn’t it be *who could*?

Comment: If that is from a novel, and if that novel was using past-tense narrative mode, and if that prose was ***not*** dialogue or direct thought, then, yes, you are right in your thinking, for the ***usual*** convention is to use past-tense verbs. But this is a matter of convention, not of grammar.

Comment: See [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/167922), [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/168665), [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/21408), [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/he-didnt-know-where-new-jersey-was?lq=1#comment343519_7969) — and many more besides. This is not a rule of actual grammar in English, just a general guideline especially meant for non-native learners. English has no strong sequence-of-tense rules to follow, and some nuance can often be made with contrasting examples, so it is both possible and useful to have both.

Comment: Could is not the past tense of *can*.  The past tense of *can* is *was able to*. "I can hit a bulls-eye now, but last week I wasn't able to. Could is used here to indicate possibility. She *could* sleep anywhere. "I'm so hungry right now. I *could* eat a bear." "Could I possibly see you tomorrow?" All are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description is taken from a novel; in that context, it is usual to refer to people using the past tense.

*Who could* relates not to the character just mentioned, but to the generic referent *one of those people,* whose characteristics can be described both by *who can* and *who could.*

Answer (score 2):

"Can" means that that someone *is able to* do XYZ. "Could" is the past tense of "can," but also can be used to express the conditional: "she could have..."

> She was one of those people who can to go to sleep at any hour and in any position.

**"One of those people" who can do XYZ *are still* those people, even though she *was* formerly one of them.** I think that's why the original sentence is acceptable, although "could" is equally viable.

Answer (score 1):

This is a delicate issue of finite vs non-finite verbs. What are they???

If you are familiar with object-oriented grammar, you would immediately hit a lit lite-bulb when I ask you to compare *classes versus objects*.

If you are a statistician, your lit lite-bulb would be *category-dimensions vs values*.

If you are a US naval officer, your lit lite-bulb would be *Nimitz-class vs The George Washington*.

There are two (i.e. I know of two)  modes of linguistics that is used for modular displacement of predicates.

- non-finite verbs
- subjunctives (general terminology, not the English language specific term)

Non-finite verbs are classes or categories of action, and therefore their actions are not bound to a specific instance.

Example of a non-finite verbs, or non-finite verb in participle form:

- I love **painting houses**.
- I love **painted houses**.

Example of finite verb clauses:

- **I am painting** this house.
- **I painted** a house last summer.

The general perspective you need to bear is there are times we need to speak of general classes of action, while at other times we need to speak of specific actions.

Examples uses of a time-independent/instance-independent modular clause (i.e. non-finite verbal clauses/phrases):

- Past participle: White-**tailed** deer are cute.
- Past participle: **Painted** doors are beautiful.
- Present participle: I am {**having** breakfast}.
- Verbal-noun gerund: This is a beautiful **painting**.
- Gerund: I love {**having** breakfast}. I have been {**having** breakfast} everyday sinec I was born. After I die, I will no longer be {**having** breakfast}.
- Subjunctive: I know of people who {**could** sleep at anytime of the day}.
- Imperative: **Do not cross** the road without a green walking light.
- Infinitive: I had advised her to {**speak** to you}.
- To-less infinitive: : I had expected that she {**need** not go to work}.
- +To-less infinitive: I had enjoyed seeing {people **laugh** at themselves}. Seeing {people **laugh** at themselves} always brightens up my life. Ten years from now I will still enjoy seeing {people **laugh** at themselves}.
- +gerund: I had enjoyed {**seeing** her {laugh at herself}}. {**Seeing** her {laugh at herself} always brightens up my life. Ten years from now I will still enjoy {**seeing** her {laugh at herself}}.
- gerund: I had enjoyed {people **laughing** at themselves}. {People **laughing** at themselves} always brightens up my life. Ten years from I would still enjoy {people **laughing** at themselves}.

#### Addendum

+A change has been made to one of the examples, due to F.E.'s advisory.

Comment: Your discussion is fine as far as it goes, but I can't help feeling that the OP will be wondering exactly what, or whose, question you are answering... :-)

Comment: Thx F.E. correction made.

Answer (score 0):

Because they still can. You would say "I met a woman this morning who was one of those people who can go to sleep at any hour and in any position."