# "I didn't know you golf" vs "I didn't know you golfed"

Tags: tenses, backshifting

While reading a popular author I came across:

> "I left my clubs at home, so I can't play."
>
> "Oh? I didn't know (that) you **golf**."

This sounds wrong, but presumably it was passed by at least one editor. To me, the past tense "golfed" would be more appropriate.  But if this way works too, what sort of construct is it?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["I didn't know you liked her" or "I didn't know you like her"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149120/i-didnt-know-you-liked-her-or-i-didnt-know-you-like-her)

Comment: I think they're both fine.  I'd personally say 'golf' because I didn't know you golf _currently_, and the past is irrelevant.

Comment: As usual, the thread that is supposed to have the answer to this OP's question (that one that is linked to via the "duplicate" label) has a bad accepted answer. The OP should search via the "backshifting" tag until they get to a thread with a decent answer--such as the one that *George Capote* linked to.

Comment: @FE - yes, George's link is the better one. I can't very well accept your answer there as the answer here, but I would if I could. (-: