# I never knew I have a sister or I had a sister

Tags: grammar, american-english

I want to say that I learned something new which I did not know before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["I didn't know you liked her" or "I didn't know you like her"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149120/i-didnt-know-you-liked-her-or-i-didnt-know-you-like-her)