# Past-tense verb + that clause: clause has to use past tense?

Tags: tenses, present-tense, backshifting, subordinate-clauses

I am writing a subordinate clause in the "Related Work" section of my academic paper. Which is correct?

> In [1], Smith *et al.* pointed out that the solution **is** feasible.

OR

> In [1], Smith *et al.* pointed out that the solution **was** feasible.

I am quite confused.

On the one hand, I remember clearly the verb tense in the "that" clause should follow that of the verb in the main sentence. Hence, "was" should be used, following "pointed".

On the other hand, Smith's work is always there and always thinks that the solution is feasible. Hence, the present tense should be used.

Which reasoning is correct?

(NOTE: The OP is asking if it is *obligatory* that the "is" verb is backshifted into "was", or if backshifting is *not allowed*, or if backshifting is *optional*. -- F.E.)

Comment: I'm afraid you've learned a zombie rule. There is no such rule about verb tenses in complement clauses; there are any number of patterns, and only the ones that don't make sense (like **She thinks I am to leave last month*) are ungrammatical.

Comment: This post on backshifting might be helpful for you: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/150743/57102

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can use either *was* or *is* but I would not use *is* in the sentence you wrote. This is a stylistic preference.

You state "Smith's work is always there and always thinks that the solution is feasible." Then why would you not think Smith et al. *are not always present* in [1]?

> In [1], Smith et al. **point out** that the solution **is** feasible.

If it was some time ago, it might be better to stick with the past, and if you feel it is necessary to point out the continuing validity of the solution, you can do that.

> In [1], Smith et al. pointed out that the solution was feasible, *an option still in use today.*

It partly depends on the (style and substance of the) rest of your paper, your preference, and the style preferences of the journal/audience to whom you will be presenting your work. I would either go with *point/is* or *pointed/was*. *Pointed/is* sounds a bit strange to my ear.

Comment: but wouldn't pointed/was lead the readers to think that the solution used to be feasible, but now it is infeasible?

Comment: @FP It shouldn't; _was at that time feasible_ might (and _used to be feasible_ would ).