# Talking about past action in the present time

Tags: grammar, past-tense

I am confused about the correctness of the following two statements:

> I thought essential oils **were** the cure to all life's problem.

And

> I thought essential oils **are** the cure to all life's problem.

Can some please help me correct this, which one is a correct statement and why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Past-tense verb + that clause: clause has to use past tense?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160893/past-tense-verb-that-clause-clause-has-to-use-past-tense)

Comment: It's not so much correct vs incorrect as it is a matter of context.

Comment: Please, migrate this question to ell.stackexchange.com