# I thought...WAS vs. I thought ....IS?

Tags: backshifting

I read this phrase: ***"I thought your essay about Internet WAS very accurate***"

I wonder why the past tense is used in here! Doesn't it have to be: "I thought your essay about Internet IS very accurate"?

Thanks all in advance.

Comment: Your topic involves ***backshifting***. Here is a recent thread with an answer that I think will satisfy you. :) http://english.stackexchange.com/a/150743/57102

Comment: Clearly this is a prelude to something very bad.  I **thought** your essay about the Internet was very accurate, but **now** I think it is total B.S.