# Dependent clause tense inheritance

Tags: grammar, tenses, backshifting, sequence-of-tenses

Is it right to tell

> 1. Five years ago he already knew that two plus two **equals** four.

or

> 2. Five years ago he already knew that two plus two **equaled** four.

?

On English classes (I live in not English speaking country) we have learnt that if present clause is dependent to past one than it turns into past. However, I did not fully agree with it and gave (the top sentence above as) an example. It caused a lot of confusion.

In my country's official pre-university English exams (one of the previous years' variants) there is a text with tasks. One of the sentences is:

```
Nurse believed that fresh air and food ____ very important in fighting soldiers' diseases.
A. are
B. were
...
```

I was really surprised when I discovered that the right answer is B. were.

My logic is: when nurse dies, it won't become unimportant. That's why A. are should be right.

Could someone please help figuring it out?

Comment: This answer post has some grammatical info on this topic of backshift: [Past tense or present tense to describe something that happened in the past but is still true?](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/150743/57102).

Comment: @F.E. It's a duplicate!

Comment: Plus the OP has much more serious issues to work on, before attempting to discover a non-existent "tense inheritance" rule. Like the difference between _tell_ and _say_, article placement, auxiliary verb constructions, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the condition expressed in the that-clause is still true, especially if it is a "general truth", it is okay to retain the present tense.

> Five years ago he already knew that two plus two **equals** four

As of January 17, 2015, two plus two **equals** four, so I would see nothing wrong with this sentence.

Let me quote from [Capital Community College Foundation's *The Guide to Grammar and Writing*'s page on Sequence of Tenses](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/sequence.htm):

> As long as the main clause's verb is in neither the past nor the past perfect tense, the verb of the subordinate clause can be in any tense that conveys meaning accurately. When the main clause verb is in the past or past perfect, however, the verb in the subordinate clause must be in the past or past perfect. The exception to this rule is when the subordinate clause expresses what is commonly known as a general truth:
>
> 1. In the 1950s, English teachers still believed that a background in Latin **is** essential for an understanding of English.
> 2. Columbus somehow knew that the world **is** round.
> 3. Slaveowners widely understood that literacy among oppressed people **is** a dangerous thing.

Thinking that a background in Latin **is** essential for an understanding of English was considered a *general truth* in the 1950, although it is not considered as such in these days.

Comment: I'd switch to past when general-truthfulness has been to all intents and purposes disproved (example (1)).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @EdwinAshworth! I also found this sentence strange.

Comment: :-) // I've eventually tracked down what I think is the correct attribution. I understand why you left it open!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I would tend to switch to the past with all of those. That is not simply because, in instances 1 and 3 they are nowadays considered untrue, but because they are more idiomatic (if idiomatic is gradable). *Columbus believed the world was round*. It was not, incidentally, only slaveowners who thought literacy dangerous. One of the 18th-century politicians I researched, William Wyndham, a Portland Whig and Sectretary of State for War, under Pitt, thought it 'would have been better if fewer people had been taught to read'.

Comment: @WS2 I prefer overall statistics to the odd example to endorse idiomaticity. On an intermediate level, Google hits for "proved that the world is round" : "proved that the world was round" are in the ratio 188 000 : 16 000.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Perhaps Americans say it differently, but *Columbus believed the world was round* sounds much better to me.

Comment: @WS2 Using present with 'accepted' 'general truths' can be useful for disambiguation. Some people believed that the Awash empties into the Red Sea / Some people believed that the Awash emptied into the Red Sea (but at some point changed its course]. Of course, the second variant remains ambiguous without context. But the first is not in any sense 'unidiomatic'; it's a valid and widely used option.