# Does the tense in that clause need to agree with the main clause?

Tags: grammar, tenses, backshifting

I don't know if the title of this question is accurate or not. My vacabulary of grammar is very limited. May you could understand me by the following example:

> 1. *She told me that the earth **is** moving around the sun.*
> 2. *She told me that the earth **was** moving around the sun.*

Which one is correct? Should the tense in that clause always agree with the tense in main clause?

Comment: They're both fine, but *moves, moved* or *goes, went* are probably more likely.

Comment: There is no tense agreement rule in English. So the answer is No.

Comment: Well, there is actually a tense agreement rule in English, but it only applies to the tense in a that-clause which is in the semantic scope of the past tense of the matrix sentence.  In the example given, if the speaker didn't wish to take responsibility for the truth of "the earth revolves about the sun", he could use "was revolving" to place responsibility on her (the person whose speech is being reported).

Comment: @Greg Lee, would you backshift in this way? "He was explaining to me that the earth *had been revolving* around the sun, when the Dominicans broke the door down and carted him away?

Comment: @TRomano, that's an interesting example.  I don't know.

Comment: This post on [backshift](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/150743/57102) might be helpful to you. EDITED: Notice that in that post is a discussion of *"Their teacher had told them that the earth moves around the sun."* :)

Comment: Sorry for duplicated. Thanks for pointing out. I did not know how to describe this question and failed in searching.