# How to use tense when saying something happened several days ago?

Tags: tenses

I'm confused when saying something happened in the past, I know the basic rule for using the past tense, like,

> I went to the church yesterday.

But it's always hard for me to write a complex sentence, like,

> I talked with Joe about this the other day, we think/thought it will/would be nice to ask customer if they need/needed this product and how many, but this can/could wait until Sep. 10.

Could anyone help to pick up the right tense and provide some explanation.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Three Ways to describe the Meeting, the Decision, the Proposal

.A. **Avoiding Tenses**  (the only tense reflects the time of the meeting)

> A meeting was held last week to discuss a plan, to create product, to
>   record thanks.
>
> There is a meeting at noon today to discuss a new Y for next year, to
>   reassess last year's results, and to evaluate current opportunities.
>
> A committee will meet next month to discuss last week's barbecue.

.B. **Using the Original Tense**

In your example, the original wass 'It will be nice,' and 'Do you need this?'

> I talked with Joe about this the other day; we think it will be nice
>   to ask customers if they need this product and how many, but this can
>   wait until Sep. 10.

.C. **Tense Sequencing** or **Back-shift**

It is perfectly acceptable to use your more formal account:

> I talked with Joe about this the other day, we thought it would be
>   nice to ask customers if they needed this product and how many, but we
>   decided it could wait until Sep. 10.

but sequence is *required* in set phrases:(originally: Do you want to see...?)
He asked if we wanted to see the film.
('Will you be there?') He said he would.

and after 'whether' (originally, 'Shall we give him a hand?')
We wondered/ we discussed whether we should give him a hand.

There is of course more information on Wikipedia [Sequence of Tenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_of_tenses) and from Cambridge Grammar '[Reported Speech](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/reported-speech-indirect-speech?q=backshift),' and '[Whether](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/if-or-whether).'

There is also a good answer here:  [Q 240479](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240479).