# Sequence of tenses with "told" and "said"

Tags: questions, sequence-of-tenses

"Who told you that the agreement has already been signed?"

I wonder whether we should observe the sequence of tenses rule and make it "Who told you that the agreement **had** already been signed?"

Comment: You can, but you don’t have to. Both work, but mean slightly different things.

Comment: Could you please tell me the difference in meanings you mentioned?

Comment: With _has_, the meaning is that the contract is **currently** in a signed state; i.e., “Who told you that the contract _is currently signed_”. With _had_, the contract was in a signed state **when the statement was made**, but may not be anymore (though it probably is, since contracts don’t usually become unsigned). “He told me he’s very angry” = he’s angry now. “He told me he was angry” = he was angry when he said it, but he may not be angry anymore.

Comment: Uh… that has nothing to do with sequence of tense, or backshift, or anything of the kind.

Whether an agreement "had or "has" been signed depends purely on the context; what the author meant, unless there were mistakes.

What the reader or scholar thinks might have been meant could have much bearing on interpreting those mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence of tenses is also called *backshift*. It is better to regard it as a common usage rather than a rule to be applied in all cases. As *The Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar* (p45) states in its  entry on *backshift*:

> ... backshift (sometimes known as the *sequence of tense rule*) is not automatic.

*The Cambridge Dictionary of English Grammar* (p318) has this extract in its entry on *sequence of tenses*:

> In classical Latin the tense of the verb in the main clause influenced
>   that of the verb in the following subordinate clause, especially in
>   reported speech. This principle was taken up by traditional
>   grammarians in  modern English.
>
> ...
>
> In formal writing and reporting, the *sequence of tenses* is usually
>   practiced, whereas in everyday discourse it is not necessarily
>   observed.

The CDEG gives examples in which observing the sequence of tenses rule would either change the meaning of the sentence or would render it ambiguous. It then states:

> In such cases, the pragmatics of communication take over to ensure
>   that the tense sequence works to support the intended meaning.

As @Janus Bahs Jacquet points out in his comment, the use of the present tense in the reported clause (*has already been signed*) indicates to the listener that the report is currently in a signed state. The present tense is used to emphasise present relevance.

The backshifted version, using the past perfect tense (*had already been signed*), places more emphasis on the time point of the signing; namely, before the reporting of it.

---

There have been numerous questions about *backshifting* on this site. Here is one that contains an answer with further extracts from reference grammars on the issue:

[Problem with backshift in reporting clauses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240479/problem-with-backshift-in-reporting-clauses)