# "You mentioned that you want" vs. "You mentioned that you wanted"

Tags: grammar, conjugation

Which is correct in this scenario?

1. "When you mentioned that you wanted this book, I knew I had to get it for you."
2. "When you mentioned that you want this book, I knew I had to get it for you."

The first sentence sounds more accurate to me, but the desire for the book has not gone away. She mentioned that she wanted it at the time, but she still wants the book.

Comment: It should be `wanted`.

Comment: they both work, but we usually like to keep tense matching

Comment: @ElgsQianChen If you want to answer the question, you can post it as an answer. And if you think it shouldn't be answered due to lack of research, and you want to put a comment, at least explain why it shouldn't be *want*.

Comment: @dandavis Why do you think they both work?

Comment: @haha: OP explained that already; _want_ is apt but _wanted_ is homogeneous.

Comment: Then post it as an answer if you think that's an answer. And then I decide to upvote/downvote it

Comment: The question here is about backshift in reported speech. There have been numerous similar questions on this site over the years. Here is one with an answer that has references from various grammar resources: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240479/problem-with-backshift-in-reporting-clauses

Comment: I appreciate the guidance. I tried to do some research, but I couldn't find a search that was specific or precise enough. The word backshift is new to me.

Comment: @Josephus. Yes, it's always difficult  to find what you want if you don't know the terminology. This aspect of grammar is also searchable under the term "_sequence of tenses_".

Comment: I suggest it’s not about back-shift in reported speech because that would apply to planned writing and this is fairly clearly about natural speaking.

Both are acceptable to the extent it does represent natural speech.

If it’s meant to reflect what the speaker should have said, given time for composition, then the first example is correct and the second… uh… isn’t.

No, Josephus; it matters not whether the desire still exists. The speaker is clearly referring to what was true at the time and nothing else…