# have+past participlet+that+Subject+IS or WAS

Tags: participles, have

Examples

1. I have always thought he is/was a good guy.
2. I have always thought a boat doesn't/didn't float.
3. I have always thought the sun rises/rose in the east.

What are the DIFFERENCES? Is there an absolutely correct tense I should use? To non-native English speakers, they will think "have always thought" is PRESENT perfect tense. It started in the past, and it's continuing to the PRESENT. Therefore, I should use "is/ doesn't/rises for example 1./2./3." Howevere, I asked some native English speakers. They say "was/didn't for example 1./2." is correct. For example 3, they say "rises and rose" both are correct. Why does this happen?

What does "I have always thought he IS a good guy." and "I have always thought he WAS a good guy." mean to you? Do they mean the same thing?

Comment: There are numerous questions on this forum about [backshifting](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/reported-speech-backshift.php), such as [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240479/problem-with-backshift-in-reporting-clauses)#

Answer (score 0):

In general, both past and present tense are common and considered correct.

However, if you want to express the fact that you've changed your mind, you use the past tense.

> I've always thought he was a good guy, but now I think he's changed.

Comment: Better yet, change "I have" to "I had"