# Past subjunctive

Tags: subjunctive-mood

In the following sentence (from [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/confirmation/)), is it grammatical to use subjunctive *were* instead of *are*?

> As emphasized in a joke attributed to American philosopher Morris Raphael Cohen (1880–1947), logic texts had to be divided in two parts: in the first part, on deductive logic, unwarranted forms of inference (deductive fallacies) **are** exposed

Which one of the two moods sounds more natural after *had to* here?

Comment: It could be the simple past "were". I cannot see any reason why the subjunctive might be relevant.

Comment: I can't see the relevance here of the ill-named past subjunctive to your example. As Colin Fine says, "were" would be a preterite (simple past) verb-form.

Comment: Please search the following sentence in [English subjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive) _Marjorie had insisted that Barbara spent the morning resting in her stateroom_. It seems to me that for the same reason a subjunctive verb can also be used here. Am I wrong in this respect?

Comment: The fact that *were* is spelled the same in both the simple past and the subjunctive is irrelevant. If used in this sentence, it would be the simple past—as per the other comments. The surrounding text doesn't warrant an interpretation of the subjunctive.

Comment: @Kaveh: You're misinterpreting the Wikipedia article. The sentence *Marjorie had insisted ...* is an example of British authors using the past indicative rather than the present subjunctive. In contemporary English, Americans otten use the subjunctive after *insisted*, but I don't believe anybody would use any flavor of the subjunctive in your sentence.

Comment: @PeterShor In the "Marjorie had insisted..." sentence, I would have ended "...that Barbara **spend** the morning resting". But that has nothing to do with the "subjunctive" - simply that it is a dependent clause. In the same way "I asked that he write me a letter". To make the verb of the dependent clause agree with the main indicative verb in this instance would surely be ungrammatical, wouldn't it?

Comment: @WS2: Apparently, lots of people in the U.K. don't think it's ungrammatical, even though Americans generally do.

Comment: @PeterShor Who are the "lots of people in the UK" who think it grammatical to force agreement of dependent clause verbs with the main verb? There are plenty who don't speak grammatical English, but I can tell you that anyone who said "I simply asked that he wrote me a letter" would not come across well in a university interview for an English degree.

Comment: @WS2 If _write_ in _I asked that he write me a letter_ is in normal indicative why isn't it inflected in agreement with its third person subject?

Comment: @Kaveh Umm, yes. My apologies. I must correct what I said, to the extent that it is the subjunctive. But in terms of tense it does not and should not agree with the past tense of the verb in the main clause. However always bear in mind that some professional grammarians (e.g. John Lawler - a contributor to this site) will argue that there is no such thing as the subjunctive.

Comment: @WS2: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_present_subjunctive) took the *Marjorie had insisted ...* from a novel by [Peter Lovesey,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Lovesey) so one assumes that both Peter Lovesey and his copyeditor think it's grammatical. Wikipedia has several other examples from British authors, as well.

Comment: @PeterShor And Lovesey graduated in English from my own Alma Mater too - University of Reading! There is a genre of modern writing in Britain which affects working-class/less than literate English. 1960s authors like Nell Dunn - *Poor Cow* is an example I have in mind. Perhaps John Osborne - *Look back in anger* also did that. Lovesey sounds as if he might be one of those. But I guess Mark Twain reproduced working-class speech in the 1870s.

Comment: @WS2: Peter Lovesey isn't obviously writing in dialect (the way Mark Twain is), but he is using an informal style which wouldn't be suited for formal writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Of Tense, Not Mood

The verb phrase *“had to be di­vided”* is **not** one of those whose
sub­or­di­nate clauses some­times take some­thing other than the
nor­mal in­dica­tive by some speak­ers and writ­ers and
oc­ca­sions.

Even if it were, there are no sub­or­di­nate
clauses here in your orig­i­nal.

That means what you are re­ally ask­ing about here is not mood but
tense; that is, whether the tense ought to use the nor­mally
in­flected present-ver­sus-pret­erite of *be*, so ei­ther the
plu­ral present *are* or else the plu­ral pret­erite *were*.

Per­haps it is both­er­ing you to see the present tense used later
in a sen­tence that first uses the pret­erite. If so, please see our
***su­per*-Fre­quently Asked Ques­tion** en­ti­tled [“He didn’t know where
New Jer­sey was”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/7964/2085)
along with its an­swers and those of [its nearly four dozen linked
ques­tions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/7964?lq=1).

## Of Moods and Modes, and Their Marking

But if you still want some­thing gov­erned by what has some­times
his­tor­i­cally been called the “sub­junc­tive” by the more, ahem,
*di­achron­i­cally* in­clined mor­phol­o­gists and syn­tac­ti­cians,
but viewed syn­chron­i­cally is ac­tu­ally just a form of modal
mark­ing us­ing a “zero”-modal (bare in­fini­tive) or else by us­ing an ex­plicit
one like *should* or *must*, then here’s what you have to do...

To get some­thing fancier so that it’s “mod­ally” marked, you
would need to use a spe­cial verb like *pro­posed* or *sug­gested*
or *in­sisted* in the main clause so that you could mod­ally mark
some other verb in a new sub­or­di­nate clause gov­erned by the
main clause.

---

#### Ex­am­ple 1

Either by us­ing the bare-in­fi­ni­tive mo­dal­ity:

> As a joke, Amer­i­can phi­los­o­pher Mor­ris Raph­ael Co­hen
> **pro­posed that** logic texts ***be* di­vided** in two parts:
>
> 1. the *de­duc­tive* part where un­war­ranted forms of in­fer­ence are *ex­posed*
> 2. the *in­duc­tive* part where un­war­ranted forms of in­fer­ence are *en­dorsed*

Or by pre­fix­ing that bare-in­fi­ni­tive with an ac­tual modal verb:

> As a joke, Amer­i­can phi­los­o­pher Mor­ris Raph­ael Co­hen
> **pro­posed that** logic texts ***should be* di­vided** in two parts:
>
> 1. the *de­duc­tive* part where un­war­ranted forms of in­fer­ence are *ex­posed*
> 2. the *in­duc­tive* part where un­war­ranted forms of in­fer­ence are *en­dorsed*

#### Ex­am­ple 2

Either by us­ing the bare-in­fi­ni­tive mo­dal­ity:

> As a joke, Amer­i­can phi­los­o­pher Mor­ris Raph­ael Co­hen
> **pro­posed that** un­war­ranted forms of in­fer­ence ***be*
> ex­posed** in the first part on de­duc­tion, and **that** they
> ***be* en­dorsed** in the sec­ond part on in­duc­tion.

Or by pre­fix­ing that bare-in­fi­ni­tive with an ac­tual modal verb:

> As a joke, Amer­i­can phi­los­o­pher Mor­ris Raph­ael Co­hen
> **pro­posed that** un­war­ranted forms of in­fer­ence ***should
> be* ex­posed** in the first part on de­duc­tion, and **that** they
> ***should be* en­dorsed** in the sec­ond part on in­duc­tion.

---

### On the Ab­sence of a Past Sub­junc­tive in Pre­sent-Day English

As you see, even if the main clause is in the pret­erite, the
sub­or­di­nate one is modally marked using just the bare in­fini­tive, never by using the
pret­erite or in the spe­cial, un­real *were* form for the unique
case of *be*.

This is an­other rea­son why call­ing some­thing “past sub­junc­tive”
in Pre­sent-Day English strains cred­i­bil­ity: we do not change
*be* to *were*, nor *spend* to *spent*, just be­cause the gov­ern­ing
clause is in the preterite.

We sim­ply use the bare in­fin­i­tive in ***all such*** sub­or­di­nate clauses, ir­re­spec­tive of the tense of the main clause.

Comment: I cant get the point in "what has some­times his­tor­i­cally been called the “sub­junc­tive” by the more, ahem, di­achron­i­cally in­clined mor­phol­o­gists and syn­tac­ti­cians, but viewed syn­chron­i­cally is ac­tu­ally just a form of modal marking using a “zero”-modal (bare in­fini­tive) or else". It seems you are telling about two *views* to the *same* thing, but the bare infinitive, AFAI, *is* different from subjunctive (be vs are). Isn't it?

Comment: And why you are calling those who speak of subjunctive _di­achron­i­cally in­clined_?

Comment: @Kaveh: In present tense, the infinitive is the same as the bare subjunctive, and has been since Shakespeare. For example, Shakespeare wrote *If this be error and upon me proved,
I never writ, nor no man ever loved,* where *be* is the present subjunctive.

Comment: @Kaveh Please see [Synchrony and diachrony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrony_and_diachrony) on Wikipedia.

Comment: "di­achron­i­cally in­clined" means they want to understand how it works and how it evolved into what it is. Not a bad thing. I am definitely one of them. The ahem I don't know what is supposed to mean, though. They might not see it as practical or relevant to modern English. In my view, the subjunctive mood is still there and calling it by its name can prove to be useful for comparative linguistics. The same we call adjectives adjectives in languages that treat them differently. It makes it easier to study when you are very logical. But it is a great answer. I wish I had read it before.