# Which one of the sentences is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar

1: In their article published 10 years ago, they concluded that the ant was an amazing creature.

2: In their article published 10 years ago, they concluded that the ant is an amazing creature.

Comment: Nothing particularly incorrect about either.  Which is more appropriate would depend on context.

Comment: It is unlikely that an academic article would conclude thar the ant is “the” amazing creature. This should probably be “an.” In which case, is, not was.

Comment: @Xanne, why was cant be used?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["He didn't know where New Jersey was"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/he-didnt-know-where-new-jersey-was) (See especially F.E.'s answer)

Comment: Because the ant still is an amazing creature.

Comment: @Xanne but it is traditonal to use the past tense even though the fact continues to be true, as explained in the linked suggested duplicate.